# CMAKE if regexp match

Tags: regex, cmake

I am trying to discover what tiny symbol is missing.

```
    if (${exename} MATCHES "^(xxx)\\w+")
        message("WERE IN TEST : " ${exename})
    endif ()
```

This fails to find names with xxx in them, I just want to find a name that contains a specific tag to add a flag.

Answer (score 1):

CMake does not support character classes in [regular expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html?highlight=regex#regex-replace); you need to use the character group with the same meaning. Furthermore I'm not sure why you add a capturing group that matches only a single string.

```
if (${exename} MATCHES "^(xxx)[A-Za-z0-9_]+")
...
```

Note that this matches strings starting with `xxx`, not strings with `xxx` anywhere. The correct regular expression for the later would be `.*xxx.*`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm very bad with regexp so I've no idea what I'm doing most of the time! Is this correct for anywhere in string? ```^(.*xxx.*.)[A-Za-z0-9_]+``` ?